# How to make an error message pops up when someone doesnt enter anything into the plain text box?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

    btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
    room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
    setTitle("Room - " + room_name);

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name", user_name);
            map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);

            input_msg.setText("");
        }
    });


    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){

        chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name + " - " + chat_msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

}

So this feature is for a chat room therefore I would like to be able to make it so users can just send blank messages into the chat room. So I would like an error to occur when a user tries to send a blank message.

Thanks!

Comment: Before you send the message check the length of the text in your `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

check for input text and display toast or whatever you want.

```
 btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name", user_name);
                map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);

              String inputMsg= usernameEditText.getText().toString();
              if (inputMsg.matches("")) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the message string before performing the data storing functionality of database like :

```
String str=input_msg.getText().toString().trim();

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()){
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name", user_name);
                map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);

                input_msg.setText("");
              }else{ 
               /// show the error msg to the user
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter the message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
              }

            }
        });
```

now in the database empty string can't store and also tell the user that need to message to send.

Comment: Nevermind fixed it with Toast.makeText(Chat_Room.this, "Please enter the message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: But when I input a message it still returns the error even though its got text in the textbox